# remove a string starting with @ in data frame column in R

Tags: r, string

Let's say if the data frame is `df` with column `foo`. Is there a way to remove a string starting with @ in data frame column in R.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(foo=c("@john is awesome than @steve", 
                                        "@steve is good","@mike is nice"))

df
                           foo
1 @john is awesome than @steve
2               @steve is good
3                @mike is nice
```

How do I remove the entire name @john,@Steve, @mike all that starts with @.

The Final output should be

```
               foo
1  is awesome than 
2          is good
3          is nice
```

I would like to get rid of all the strings from a column `foo` in data frame `df` that start with delimiter @.

Comment: `gsub("@.*?[ ]| @.*?$","",df$foo)
[1] "is awesome than" "is good"         "is nice"`

Comment: `within.list(df, {foo <- gsub("[ ]*\\@[^ ]+", "", foo)})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of mine and Richard Scriven's comments.

```
df$foo <- gsub(" ?@\\w+ ?", "", df$foo)
df
#               foo
# 1 is awesome than
# 2         is good
# 3         is nice
```

The `@\\w+` matches the ampersat followed by one or more letters.
The `?` matches an optional space at the beginning and the end.

So altogether it looks for a match of

```
[optional single space]@[one word][optional single space]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the package `stringr` and use `str_replace_all` to match the regular expression starting with `@` and any following word as:

```
library("stringr")

str_replace_all(df$foo, " ?@\\w+ ?", "")

[1] "is awesome than steve" 
[2] "is good"             
[3] "is nice"
```