# Remove a whole word starting with a pattern

Tags: r, string

I would like to remove all words starting with the pattern "R-HSA-" in a vector. For instance, given the following vector:

`a <- c ("Formation Of ATP By Chemiosmotic Coupling R-HSA-163210", "Cristae Formation R-HSA-8949613"`                                                                                         , "Mitochondrial Biogenesis R-HSA-1592230")

I would need it to become this, i.e., removal of the substring starting with "R-HSA-"

```
> a
[1] "Formation Of ATP By Chemiosmotic Coupling"
[2] "Cristae Formation"                       
[3] "Mitochondrial Biogenesis"
```

I tried to work staring from this approach, but it didn't work for me: [remove a string starting with @ in data frame column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377146/remove-a-string-starting-with-in-data-frame-column-in-r)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sub(' R-HSA.*', '', a)`